# 1 Bone driver, 4 shape keys

Tags: rigging, drivers, shape-keys

I have a setup where there is a square with a shapekey on each corner and I want to use a bone to drive the shape keys as shown in this animation:

[image]

However, I've fiddled with curves and tried a couple of expressions (I'm not good with those), but I cant get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could add a bone set up on the corners which would add 4 additional bones to your current set up. Add a two bones in the middle of the top of the outside square, where one would stay stationary and the other would be restricted to the X-axis & copy the X displacement of the bone that is animated. Then, you could set up a driver to use the displacement difference of those two bones as + or -.

Comment: that method seems sound, but I'd rather try another. This will end up adding more bones to an already complex rig (not shown)